# Why is Chrome Rendering Rails Pages So Slowly When Using POW?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome, rack-pow

When using Chrome with a POW `.dev` domain, page loads are incredibly slow.

There is a long delay between Rails finishing its work and the page being rendered to the screen.

Running the same app on a `.dev` domain in Safari or Firefox results in instant page load. As does running an alternate server locally on localhost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The specifics of getting it to work on OSX are as follows:

1. Open `System Preferences`
2. Open `Network`
3. Open `Advanced`
4. Click `Proxies` tab
5. in the field labelled *Bypass proxy settings for Hosts & Domains*, add `*.dev`
6. Click `OK`
7. Click `Apply`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but with a different solution.  Under systems preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> DNS I added localhost 127.0.0.1 as a nameserver before any other nameservers.  This helps to resolve the .dev domains much faster.